# Displaying degree symbol on webpage

Tags: php, symbols

I have a program which extracts GPS coordinates from metadata and imports the results onto a database. I then display the data using PHP on a webpage.

My problem - I've recently created a new template but for whatever reason, it is no longer showing the degrees symbol '°' but a '�'.

I just find it strange that it works with one template, but not the other?

I've tried changing fonts, but had no luck

Comment: "I have a feeling it might be to do with the CSS but have no idea which part?" Nope. The degree symbol should be converted to `&deg;` - usually via something like `htmlentities()`.

Comment: For starters, you should check you are saving your file with the correct encoding that matches your webpage's encoding

Comment: Why would it differ on the templates then? The only difference is the CSS. The PHP is exactly the same as it's just been copied.

Comment: What is the encoding of the files? UTF8, iso-8859-1?

Comment: This is encoding issue. Apart from that you should not store degree character in db. Just store the value and in UI add the unit with it

Comment: Try `utf8_encode`. Also it seems the Unicode character is cut off. For Unicode text processing use `mb_*` string functions

Answer (score 10):

See [DEGREE CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm).

Specifically, HTML Entity: `&deg;`.

Check that you have the proper docstring and character encoding in both templates to make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

`utf8_encode('YOUR TEXT');`

[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) converts the string data from the ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your PHP file with UTF-8 encoding.
2. Serve your PHP file with charset=UTF-8.
3. Add a META-tag in your HTML with charset=UTF-8.

This will solve (almost) all of your unicode character problems.

Comment: Rygu - Thanks. Although this wasn't the way I corrected things, it did point me in the right direction. Deleting the line: 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"/>

Answer (score 0):

When you input or pull the data from you database, use `htmlentities()`

you can find a good guide on this function a here http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

For degree celcius in html

```
<span>&#8451;</span>
```